# How to display photo albums in iOS12.4 as a list rather than an array of thumbnails?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, ui

I dislike the array of thumbnails or large icons as a user interface. Is there a way to get my iPhone XR running iOS 12.4 to display my photo albums as a list?